# Nullable enum properties not supported in OrmLite for ServiceStack 3?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I'm using ServiceStack 3 and OrmLite.
One of my data classes has a nullable enum property like this:

```
[Alias("CALL_SESSION")]
public class CallSession
{
    ...
    [Alias("RESULT")]
    public CallSessionResultEnum? Result { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In my Oracle DB the field `RESULT` is a `NULLABLE NUMBER`.

When I try to retrieve `CallSession` like this:

```
cn.Where<CallSession>(x => ....)
```

I get an exception `specified cast is not valid`.
It works fine if I switch the field type in my class to a simple `int?`. Am I correct in thinking that OrmLite does not support nullable enums?

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect override of method ConvertDbValue in your OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider:

```
    public override object ConvertDbValue(object value, Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            var val = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(type, val))
                throw ExHelper.Argument(Errors.Common_EnumValueNotFound, val, type.FullName);

            return val;
        }
    }
```

Solution:

```
    public override object ConvertDbValue(object value, Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            var val = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(type, val))
                throw ExHelper.Argument(Errors.Common_EnumValueNotFound, val, type.FullName);

            return base.ConvertDbValue(value, type);
        }
    }
```